# Cleaner way to store store data using dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to store the follwoing:

```
arr1 = arr[arr1inds]
arr2 = arr[arr2inds]
arr3 = arr[arr3inds]
arr4 = arr[arr4inds]
arr5 = arr[arr5inds]
arr6 = arr[arr6inds]
arr7 = arr[arr7inds]
```

Comment: what does arr look like ?

Answer (score 1):

Go two-dimensional:

```
arr2d = []
arr2d[1] = arr[arr1inds]
arr2d[2] = arr[arr2inds]
arr2d[3] = arr[arr3inds]
...
```